# How to fix _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable error on Raspberry Pi python code?

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I'm running code on a Raspberry Pi. It is a code that runs, within a function, a little snippet of using tkinter to detect key presses. If you put in the Konami code, then it outputs "You are pro.". This code works fine (shown below), but does it work if inside a function like it is on the Raspberry Pi?

The loop on the Pi takes in typed input, submitted with enter. Each keyword enters a function. For example, 'break' exits the main loop completely. Entering 'ping' would bring you to a ping system. For this, I write (translated from python to english): if you input 'code', you will go into the tkinter keypress system. Here's the system. The import tkinter as tk is not written within the inner tkinter function. It is written at the beginning of the whole program.

```
import tkinter as tk
list = ['0']
def key(event):
if event.keysym == 'Return':
    root.destroy()
if event.char == 'Backspace':
    list= ['0']
if even.char == event.keysym:
    if event.char == "b":
        list.append('b')
    if event.char == "a":
        list.append('a')
elif len(event.char)==1:
    print('')
else:
    # f1 to f12, shift keys, caps lock, Home, End, Delete ...
    if (event.keysym == 'Up'):
        list.append('Up')
    if (event.keysym == 'Down'):
        list.append('Down')
    if (event.keysym == 'Left'):
        list.append('Left')
    if (event.keysym == 'Right'):
        list.append('Right')
root = tk.Tk()
print( "Press a key (Escape key to exit):" )
root.bind_all('<Key>', key)
# don't show the tk window
root.withdraw()
root.mainloop()
if (list == ['0', 'Up', 'Up', 'Down', 'Down', 'Left', 'Right', 'Left', 'Right', 'b', 'a']):
print ("You are pro.")
```

The program works just fine until I type in 'code' as the command to start the function. The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/mnt/clock.py", line 391, in <module>
        root = tk.Tk()
    File "/use/lib/python3.3/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1701, in __init__
        self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, use Tk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable.
```

I went through the raspberry pi files to see if the __init__.py code was different than the code on windows. Of course, it is the same.

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Are you running the Pi in Desktop mode? I'd venture to guess that you're in console mode.

Comment: I'm running it it console mode, yes. Although I no longer am running this system, I'd still like to know the answer. I think its perhaps the raspberry pi did not have python 2.7.10 installed correctly or because it does not support some functions of tkinter. Also I'm practically out of memory on it - I don't know how much memory is need to run the tkinter process, or if needs memory at all.

Comment: Basically, the error says that there is no desktop to actually launch the graphical interface. You need to use the `startx` command to start the visual environment then run your file as you would normally do.